# Show that every existential sentence is preserved upwards

Tags: number-theory, logic, model-theory

> A sentence is existential if it is of the form $\exists x_1 ...
>  \exists x_nR$ and $R$ has no further quantifiers. A sentence is
>   preserved upwards if and only if whenever it is true in an
>   interpretation $\mathcal{P}$, and there is an embedding of
>   $\mathcal{P}$ in another interpretation $\mathcal{Q}$, then it is true
>   in $\mathcal{Q}$. Show that every existential sentence is preserved
>   upwards.

I'm not sure how proofs of this nature are ordinarily constructed. So lets assume the question, that every existential sentence is preserved upwards. This means that for a sentence $\exists x_1 ...\exists x_nR$ that is true in an interpretation $\mathcal{P}$, where $\mathcal{P}$ is embedded within another interpretation $\mathcal{Q}$, the sentence is also true in $\mathcal{Q}$. I figure that this is a direct result of isomorphism:

> If there is an isomorphism between interpretations $\mathcal{P}$ and
>   $\mathcal{Q}$ under language $L$, then for every sentence $A$ of $L$:
>   $\mathcal{P} \models A$ if and only if $\mathcal{Q} \models A$.

But I'm not sure how to apply that result to existential quantifiers in a particular sentence $R$.

Comment: Start by proving that quantifier free sentences are preserved upwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\varphi:\mathcal{P}\to\mathcal{Q}$ be an embedding between two interpretation. Let $P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be a quantifier-free formula which only have free variables $x_1$, $\cdots$, $x_n$. Then $\mathcal{P}\models P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ iff there is $d_1,\cdots,d_n\in|\mathcal{P}|$ such that $d_1$, $\cdots$, $d_n$ satisfies $P$ (in $\mathcal{P}$). Consider $\varphi(d_1)$, $\cdots$, $\varphi(d_n)$ in $\mathcal{Q}$. You can check that $\varphi(d_1)$, $\cdots$, $\varphi(d_n)$ satisfies $P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ in $\mathcal{Q}$.

Comment: It seems like the last sentence (the "check") is just a result of your definition of $\varphi$. If it takes instances in $\mathcal{P}$ to $\mathcal{Q}$ then applying the $\varphi$ function to all these $d_i$'s will satisfy them in $\mathcal{Q}$ thus satisfying $P$. Is the application that straightforward?

Comment: @user1038665 Sorry, I do not understand your comment. Can you write the comment once again?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My question is: how do we check that $\varphi(d_1),...,\varphi(d_n)$ satisfies $P(x_1,...,x_n)$ in $\mathcal{Q}$?

Comment: I don't know the exact definition of homomorphism between two interpretation, but as I guess, the proof of this statement is given by definition of homomorphism and induction for formulas.

Comment: Try to prove it by induction : if $P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ is quantifier-free formula with only have free variable $x_1,\cdots,x_n$, and $\varphi$ be a homomorphism between $\mathcal{P}$ to $\mathcal{Q}$. Then $\mathcal{P}\models P(d_1,d_2,\cdots,d_n)$ implies $\mathcal{Q}\models P(\varphi(d_1),\cdots,\varphi(d_n))$.

Comment: If $P=R(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be a relation, then $\mathcal{P}\models P(d_1,\cdots,d_n)$ implies $\mathcal{Q}\models P(\varphi(d_1),\cdots,\varphi(d_n)$ by definition of homomorphism (as I think). In another cases you can it by induction for formula.

Comment: @user1038665: don't think about homomorphisms. Just assume that $P$ is a subset of $Q$ with the induced structure.